# Vector length generalization

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am currently working on a software implementation of matrices and vectors. (No, this isn't a programming related question!)

As far as I understand, vectors in $R_n$ can be described as a special case of matrices, where the width of the matrix is always $1$.

For using the vectors later on, I need to be able to calculate the length of a vector.

As far as I understand, the length of a vector with $n$ dimensions can be calculated with:

$$|\vec{v}| = \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 + ... + v_n^2}$$

Now I am asking myself if there is a generalization of this for matrices of any width and length, how it is called and how to calculate it, and what it would be used for.

Comment: "*...vectors can be described as a special case of matrices, where the width of the matrix is always 1..*" Many early examples of vectors for the not-math inclined, that might be true.  For finite dimensional vector spaces, that might be okay in the sense that they could be rewritten in that form but with possibly frustrating addition rules that aren't normal to you.  Unfortunately, vectors are much more general than that and we don't limit ourselves like this.  For example, the set of all real functions is also considered a vector space, but there is no way to write a function in that form.

Comment: "*...the length of a vector with $n$ dimensions can be calculated with...*"  That is one very specific [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) for one very specific [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) called the euclidean norm in euclidean space.  Most vector spaces have infinitely many different norms.  "*...is there a generalization of this for matrices...*" [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: @JMoravitz How can I edit my question to specifically talk about the vectors I mean?

Comment: Refer to them as "*vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.*"  That at least specifies the set.  To be completely unambiguous, the "addition" should also be specified as well as the scalar multiplication, but since $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual rules is *so common*, it is common practice to leave that specification out and let people tacitly assume that is the addition and scalar multiplication you mean, and you only usually specify the addition and such used if it is a more exotic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call length of a vector is usually called its norm. And, yes, matrices have norms, too. For instance,$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\ldots&a_{nn}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\right\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n{a_{ij}}^2}.$$

Comment: Awesome, am I right to assume the matrix norm will evaluate to the same values as my example when used with a vector? And, just to be sure, is $\sum_{i,j=1}^n$ the same as $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n$?

Comment: @MarkusAppel Yes (to both questions).